# Why are the following two statements equivalent?

Tags: polynomials

I was reading some time series material and I came across this:

> the condition for causality is that $1 - \phi_1 z - ... - \phi_pz^p \neq 0$ for all $|z| \leq 1$ ,i.e. the zeros / roots of the polynomial $\phi(z) = 1 - \phi_1 z - ... - \phi_pz^p$ must **all** be greater than 1 in absolute value.

Now, what I do not understand is how does the statement

> the condition for causality is that $1 - \phi_1 z - ... - \phi_pz^p \neq 0$ for all $|z| \leq 1$

translates into this ?

> the zeros / roots of the polynomial $\phi(z) = 1 - \phi_1 z - ... -\phi_pz^p$ must **all** be greater than 1 in absolute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is a root $r$ with $\lvert r\rvert < 1$. Then we must have that
$$1 - \phi_1 r - ... - \phi_p r^p = 0$$
while $\lvert r\rvert<1$, which directly contradicts the first statement. Thus there is no such $r$.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is basically saying that the polynomial doesn't have any roots z such that |z|≤1, so they must all be greater than 1 in absolute value.